# Pass json and deserialize form in django

Tags: json, django, django-forms, django-serializer

The issue is next: I send some post data with ajax to server. This data looks like:

```
data = {
  form : $(this).serialize(),
  some_array: [2,3,4,1]
}
```

How to get form object in django? `request.POST['form']` returns a string with a form. I'm trying to use `import json` library.

But, when I run 
`value = json.load(request.POST['some_array'])` or 
`form = json.load(request.POST['form'])` 
it doesn't work.

Printing `request.POST['form']` returns the following:

`u'csrfmiddlewaretoken=I3LWAjfhZRGyd5NS3m9XcJkfklxNhxOR& address_city=%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2& address_street=2& address_building=3& delivery_time=2015-05-15'`

Comment: remove extra indents in code and add some spaces in content

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The form data is not encoded in JSON but as a query string.
You can use [`urlparse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) from the standard library to parse that query string.

Example:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs


form_data = parse_qs(request.POST['form'].encode('ASCII'))  # Query strings use only ASCII code points so it is safe.

# To access address_city:
address_city = form_data['address_city'][0].decode('utf-8')

# If you plan to pass form_data to a Django Form,
# use QueryDict instead of parse_qs:
from django.http import QueryDict


form_data = QueryDict(request.POST['form'].encode('ASCII'))
```

Comment: dou you know the right way to send some data alongside with form data? Because, if I do as described above, the fields of my form looks a little stange, e.g. if I send only form then `form.cleaned_data['address_city']` returns Kyiv, but when I send form as a query string, then `form.cleaned_data['address_city']` looks like `u'[u\\'\\xd0\\x9a\\xd0\\xb8\\xd1\\x97\\xd0\\xb2\\']'`

Comment: @Andrew I edited my answser to take into account string encoding. `parse_qs` needs a byte string as input, not a unicode object.

Comment: 2021 and this worked like a charm for me. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1

Alternatively to aumo 's answer, and assuming you are using jQuery, you may actually want to use [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) instead of [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/), to generate a JSON object that you can then [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and POST.

```
data = {
  form : $(this).serializeArray(),
  some_array: [2,3,4,1]
};

$.ajax(url, {
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  type: 'POST',
});
```

As you've pointed out in comments, the format of `serializeArray` JSON output is not easily usable by a Django form, and requires further processing, after deserializing the content through [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load).

```
data = json.load(request)
value = data['some_array']

form_data = {}
for f in data['form']:
    if f not in form_data:
        form_data[f['name']] = f['value']
    elif not isinstance(form_data[f['name']], list):
        form_data[f['name']] = [form_data[f['name']], f['value']]
    else:
        form_data[f['name']].append(f['value'])

form = MyForm(data=form_data)
```

#### Solution 2

After taking another look at the code, it might be better (and more generic for future safeness) to serialize the form data to proper json format in the frontend.

Although there are many solutions to this; my best bet would be to go with a tried/popular library such as [jquery-serialize-object](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object), the code change would be small:

```
<script src="jquery.serialize-object.min.js"></script>
<script>
    data = {
      form : $(this).serializeObject(),
      some_array: [2,3,4,1]
    };

    $.ajax(url, {
      data : JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType : 'application/json',
      type : 'POST',
    });
</script>
```

And then the server code would be much simpler

```
data = json.load(request)
value = data['some_array']
form = MyForm(data=data['form'])
```

Comment: The thing is that `serializeArray` returns an *array* (of `{name: ..., value: ...}` mappings) not a mapping of name -> values so the behaviour is different and requires extra processing server side. Another thing, `request.body` is a string (of bytes) so you must use `json.loads`, you could do `json.load(request)` though.

Comment: I like `json.load(request)`, I forgot that [HttpRequest implements __iter__](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.__iter__). You are absolutely correct about `serializeArray`, I've updated my example; though you can easily create a JSON object with the names as properties or [use an existing solution](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object)

Comment: The only issue that remains is if you have several entries with the same name value, the last value overwrites the others. This code thus does not work with multi selects for example. (yes I am getting boring)

Comment: You got me there, I tend to lean more on the solution of posting an "already properly formatted json" to begin with (making the frontend template more generic/independent of server). Please refer to [jquery-serialize-object](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object) for details