# The right way to send some data alongside with form

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms

I have a page of user oders, where displayed products in cart and a form with fields like: `address`, `mobile number` etc. I catch `submit` with jquery, and I need to send next data to server: my form and a dictionary `{id_of_product:choosen_ammount}`. I need to send that dictionary, because I check whether there is such ammount of product as user choose. If not, then send some error. I use ajax. My send data looks:

```
data = {
            form : $(this).serialize(),
            products: somedict
        }
```

In django I do next:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs
form = parse_qs(request.POST['form'])
    if request.POST:
        order_form = OrderForm(data=form)
```

But I faced a problem: it saves not correct data to database. For example it saves text string like:`[u'\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb8\xd1\x97\xd0\xb2']` . I tried to check what returns `order_form.cleaned_data['address_city']`, but it returns the same.
So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: What does somedict look like? Can you post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Django's [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects).

```
from django.http import QueryDict


# Encode your form data to a byte string.
form_data = QueryDict(request.POST['form'].encode('ASCII'))
order_form = OrderForm(data=form_data)
```

Note: first part of the problem: [Pass json and deserialize form in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946436/deserialize-form-in-django/29946618#29946618)